# Can I customize the CakePHP config folder location?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, bootstrapping

I am hoping to deploy several instances of an application on a single server and I would like to have custom database configuration files for each.

Any ideas on how I could change the path of the CakePHP config folder either via some sort of Configure:: variable or via the webroot/index.php or bootstrap file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can deploy multiple applications on the same Cake core. This is covered in the Deployment section of the manual. See [Multiple CakePHP applications using the same core](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/deployment.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

from cakephp 2.0 you can give fallback paths for your controller, configs etc

so you can first give path of your local common directory and then the application's config directory path.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/app.html#App::build

Comment: That shows Helpers, Models, and Controllers - how would you specify Config folder?